# Autocomplete matching in Elastic Search

Tags: search, elasticsearch, autocomplete, full-text-search, search-engine

So I have a an `identifier` string field in elastic search that contains values like `D123`, `M1`, `T23` etc.

I am trying to build autocomplete into the search for this field such that a query of `D12` might match `D12`, `D120`, `D121`, ..., `D1210` etc.

Currently I have constructed a custom edge ngram filter and analyzer as such:

```json
"filter": {
  "autocomplete_filter": {
    "type": "edgeNGram",
    "min_gram": 2,
    "max_gram": 10
  }
}

"analyzer": {
  "autocomplete": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "whitespace",
      "filter": {"lowercase", "autocomplete_filter"}
  }
}
```

And in my mapping I use this on the `identifier` field when **indexing**:

```json
"identifier": {
  "type": "string",
  "analyzer": "autocomplete",
  "search_analyzer": "standard"
}
```

This means the ngrams that are indexed for `D1234` are `D1`, `D12`, `D123` and `D1234`.

To query this I am doing as follows:

```json
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "should": {
      "match": {
        "identifier": {
          "query": "D12",
          "fuzziness": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns results from longest to shortest, so that `D12` appears at the end of the results. How would I go about ensuring the shortest possible identifier has the highest relevance score?

My guess is that the `D12` query is matching the ngrams like so: `[{D12}, {D12}3, {D12}34]` and elastic search goes "Oh great, 3 matches!" rather than the 1 `[{D12}]` that the `D12` result would give.

I guess one solution might be not partially matching those ngrams so that elastic search sees `[{D12}]` for both results but ranks `D12` higher than `D1234` since it matched 1/2 of the ngrams rather than 1/4. I'm not sure how to configure elastic search to give this result though.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of ES you are using?

Comment: did the solution work?

Comment: Hey bud, sorry I haven't had a chance to implement it and try it for myself yet. Will it work with additional `bool` conditions or will it overwrite these?

Comment: no problem bud, I am almost certain it will work with different bool conditions, but if you can post your full query, I can test it and be sure 100%

Comment: Its cool bud I'll have look at it soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [script based sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting), but first you need to map you `identifier` field as `multi-fields` like this

```
"identifier": {
    "type": "string",
    "analyzer": "autocomplete",
    "search_analyzer": "standard",
    "fields": {
        "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
}
```

You need to do this because if you `sort` directly on `identifier` then you will get same results because all of them will be having **2 letter tokens** due to `edge ngram filter`. After that this will give you desired results

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": {
        "match": {
          "identifier": {
            "query": "D12",
            "fuzziness": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "doc['identifier.raw'].value.length()",
      "order": "asc",
      "type": "number"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks again for your answer. This worked when I wanted just to query this one field but completely overrode the relevance score when other queries were incorporated. Not sure I'll be able to go down the _script sorting path for my requirements.

Comment: Also just thought I'd mention of any one else, inline scripting is disabled by default in newer versions of ES (I'm using ES 2.1). You can enable this. or create the script as a `.groovy` file and place it in you're `/config/scripts/` directory.